# Swift mailer changed setting with default when queue:work

Tags: laravel-5, swiftmailer

I have a swift mailer in Laravel 5.8 and it sends an email with the user SMTP setting.
It works well manually, but when I use this within the queue, the mailer setting is reverted to the default setting.

**The code is like this**

```
if ($own_stmp) {
    $transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport($user->mail_host, $user->mail_port))
        ->setUsername($user->mail_username)
        ->setPassword($user->mail_password);
} else {
    $transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport(\Config::get('mail.host'), \Config::get('mail.port')))
        ->setUsername(\Config::get('mail.username'))
        ->setPassword(\Config::get('mail.password'));
}

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);
    
// Create a message
if ($own_stmp) {
    $message = (new Swift_Message($subject))
        ->setFrom([$user->mail_from_address => $agent->name])
        ->setTo([$lead->email => $lead->name])
        ->setReplyTo($agent->email)
        ->addPart($content, 'text/html');
} else {
    $message = (new Swift_Message($subject))
        ->setFrom([\Config::get('mail.from.address') => $agent->name])
        ->setTo([$lead->email => $lead->name])
        ->setReplyTo($agent->email)
        ->addPart($content, 'text/html');
}

// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

As you can see, it changes email setting by **$own_smtp** flag.

This is really working well, but when I use this with

```
php artisan queue:work
```

It is skipped custom user setting and send with default setting.

What is wrong? How to solve this?